# Square POS GUI widgets

Tags: widget, square

I like the REST APIs for accessing back-end data, but does the Square POS provide a mechanism for including a custom GUI widget within the POS screens?  For example a custom loyalty widget such that it's easily accessible at the press of a button while checking someone out?
If not, how does someone add custom functionality hopefully without having separate hardware or switching to separate software?

Answer (score 0):

Square does not allow you to add any "custom widgets" or the like to the Point of Sale app. Generally speaking most people doing loyalty integrations either create their own point of sale experience with your loyalty functionality built in, or use the Rest APIs (at the expense of accessibility)